# html table go back to first row second column

Tags: c#, html, html-table

In this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/u2kgdr4o/)

is the output I am looking for, table headers on the left and corresponding data on the right....
once I hit the end of `foreach (DataColumn c in dr.Table.Columns)` is it possible to say - go back to the first row, second column?

```
foreach (DataRow dr in currentAttribs.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn c in dr.Table.Columns) 
    {
        headerRow = "<tr><th>" + c.ColumnName.ToString() + "</th></tr><br><br>";
        Literal lcl = new Literal();
        lcl.Text = headerRow;
        divFeatureInfo.Controls.Add(lcl);
    }

    foreach (object column in dr.ItemArray)
    {
        tableRow = "<TR><TD>" + column.ToString() + "</TD></TR><br><br>";
        Literal lc = new Literal();
        lc.Text = tableRow;
        divFeatureInfo.Controls.Add(lc);
    }
}
```

this code is giving me the output:

```
id

Geom

Day

05

489090

Monday
```

I would like:

```
id        05

Geom      489090

Day      Monday
```

thanks for any replies

Comment: do you know how many columns you will have? If so use a for loop for your columns and a loop for your rows inside of it

Comment: always 2 columns yes but could be any number of rows

Answer (score 0):

Does the lenght of dr.ItemArray always equal count of dr.Table.Columns?
If so, make a for loop, reference the array items and the table columns by id and just write all data in one string.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in currentAttribs.Rows)
{
    string row;
    for(var i = 0; i < dr.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        row = "<tr><th>" + dr.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString() + "</th><td>" + + dr.ItemArray[i].ToString() + "</td></tr><br><br>";
        Literal lcl = new Literal();
        lcl.Text = row;
        divFeatureInfo.Controls.Add(lcl);
    }
}
```

Of course, if you can't make sure that the count/length is always the same you will either get some nasty IndexOutOfBoundsException or miss some data in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by using GOTO but it's verry forbidden :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/13940fs2.aspx

Regards